# Hacer dos count a dos tablas diferentes a la vez SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Hola buenas tengo un problema a la hora de hacer dos count a la vez de diferentes tablas en una base de datos sql.

Resumidamente está sería la base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE likes(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   post INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY fk_post(post) REFERENCES posts(id)
);

 CREATE TABLE comments(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   post INT NOT NULL,
   comment VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY fk_comment(post) REFERENCES posts(id)
);

INSERT INTO posts(title) VALUE ('post 1'),('post 2'),('post 3');
INSERT INTO likes(post) VALUE (1),(1),(2);
INSERT INTO comments(post,comment) VALUE (1,'hola'),(1,'hola'),(3,'hola'),(3,'hola'), (2,'hola');
```

El objetivo es que la consulta devuelva lo siguiente:

| title | likes | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| post1 | 2 | 2 |
| post2 | 1 | 1 |
| post3 | 0 | 2 |

Yo he conseguido hacer un count haciendo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
posts.title,
count(l.post) likes
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN likes l ON posts.id = l.post
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Con está consulta devuelve lo siguiente(y si lo hago con la tabla 'comment' también funciona):

| title | likes |
| --- | --- |
| post1 | 2 |
| post2 | 1 |
| post3 | 0 |

El problema es a la hora de hacer los dos count a la vez, yo he intentado lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
posts.title,
count(l.post) likes,
count(c.post) comments
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN likes l ON posts.id = l.post
LEFT JOIN comments c ON posts.id = c.post
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Pero devuelve lo siguiente:

| title | likes | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| post1 | 4 | 4 |
| post2 | 1 | 1 |
| post3 | 0 | 2 |

(**ACTUALIZO**)

He encontrado la forma de hacer los dos count, con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
p.id,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post = p.id) as likes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE post = p.id) as comments
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM posts) p;
```

El problema es que al poner en el SELECT el p.title me da error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes obtener el resultado que necesitas utilizando [`COUNT(DISTINCT exp)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count)

#### Ejemplo:

```
SELECT
  posts.title,
  COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) likes,
  COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) comments
FROM posts
  LEFT JOIN likes l ON posts.id = l.post
  LEFT JOIN comments c ON posts.id = c.post
GROUP BY posts.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/52Xvht8Wsqdcb9Wa3zRFtY/0)</kbd>